# Highcharts show only every 3rd point/marker?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to tell highchats to show every 3rd point or marker on a series?

I have a series with many points and it looks very crowded. I would like to display fewer points if possible.

Comment: 1) You can look at the **dataGrouping** feature of **Highstock** - Highcharts does not have an equivalent property. 2) Aside from data grouping, a more appropriate way of reducing the number of points would be to aggregate your data. For example, if your data is daily, show weekly totals or averages instead.  Simply dropping data points is, generally, a *really* bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could be able to preprocess series data and leave only the third elements inside the series object. That's the only way.

Examples [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing)